# Handlebars does not recognize helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I found this helper online that checks whether a variable is equal to a certain string. I tried to add this helper to my index.hbs file, but I get the following error: Missing helper: "if_eq"

Can someone tell me how I can fix this? I did what they asked me to do in in the official Handlebars docs, so I don't understand. I use NodeJS/Express, but without `require('handlebars')` or `require('express-handlebars')`, because that's how express-generator generated it for me.

index.hbs:

```
<script>
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b)
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
</script>

{{#each tasks}}
    {{#if_eq status 'unfinished'}}
        [do something]
    {{else}}
        [do something else]
    {{/if_eq}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: So you're not using handlebars nor express-handlebars... what are you using to render a handlebars template? I can see the problem but I need more info to give you a suitable answer.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I use `res.render()`. In app.js I have set Handlebars as my view engine in the following way: `app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande So I looked at my node_modules and express-generator has included hbs. Does that mean I have to add the helper in app.js? If so, why is it not mentioned in the official docs? According to [them](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) "helpers can be accessed from any context in a template."

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) uses: [hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs) package as you can see in [here](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/bin/express-cli.js#L299):

[image]

So you need to first register the helper in the server side, like this:

```
const hbs = require('hbs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
    if(a == b)
        return opts.fn(this);
    else
        return opts.inverse(this);
});
//... rest of your server code
```

Drop the helper from `index.hbs` since that's for registering the helper in the client side, and you're rendering handlebars in the server side.

**index.hbs**

```
{{#each tasks}}
    {{#if_eq status 'unfinished'}}
        [do something]
    {{else}}
        [do something else]
    {{/if_eq}}
{{/each}}
```